# Evaluate $\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{y^2-3}^{5-y^2}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

In the black I evaluated the integral and I got 64/3, now I need to evaluate the same integral with $\color{red}{dydx}$ .in the $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ color is my attempt, I don't think that my attempt is correct.

> Can someone please tell me what is my mistake in my attempt (in the blue color)?

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{y^2-3}^{5-y^2}dxdy=\frac{64}{3}$$

$$\color{blue}{\int_{-3}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{x-3}}^{\sqrt{x-3}}dydx+\int_{1}^{5}\int_{-\sqrt{x-5}}^{\sqrt{x-5}
}dydx}$$

[image]

Comment: This is a dupilcate.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{x+3}$?

Comment: Shouldn't you have $\sqrt{5-x}$ in the second set of limits?

Comment: It is duplicate, but I can't delete because the answer

Comment: @Nehorai As you have > 250 rep, you can close your own question as a duplicate. Simply click the close button, then duplicate, enter the post, click close and the Community user will close the question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{-3}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{x+3}}^{\sqrt{x+3}}dydx + \int_{1}^{5} \int_{-\sqrt{5-x}}^{\sqrt{5-x}}dydx=\\2 (\int_{-3}^{1}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x+3}}dydx + \int_{1}^{5} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{5-x}}dydx)$$[image]